# Рамка, которая двигается по картинке

Tags: wpf, .net, графика

Допустим, на форме есть картинка.

Я хочу сделать так, что бы по картинке (в пределах) можно было двигать некоторую прямоугольную рамку, размеры которой пользователь может измерять (больше, меньше). А затем, взять область изображения и допустим вырезать в новую картинку.

1. Я хочу знать какой примитив мне в этом может помочь. Вроде, в WinForms что-то подобное решается созданием прозрачной формы. А как с этим обстоят дела в WPF? Наверное, так же должен описать какой-нибудь кастомный контрол?
2. Как я могу высчитывать координаты рамки относительно картинки на форме?
   Точнее, я предполагаю как их ручками вычислить, но может быть в WPF есть способы вычислить их автоматически.

Comment: Ваш вопрос довольно-таки общий, но основные моменты можете взять из указанного топика ^^^ Если есть вопросы по конкретным узким местам в реализации, то лучше задать их отдельно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP а где сам топик?

Comment: @vitidev, см. дубликат